# Given an iOS app’s iTunes identifier, how do you find which countries it’s available in?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes-store

I have an app that showcases other apps, but some of those apps are only available in certain country's iTunes stores. Up until now I've just posted whack a mole to try to figure out which stores an app is available in, but that's annoying and error prone. Is there a way to get which stores an app is available in easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using [this list of available stores](https://gist.github.com/daFish/5990634) and writing a Python script that pings the [iTunes API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/iTuneSearchAPI/LookupExamples.html) for each one to see if a property is available in each one.